# How to run meshcli application from the SilvairGit / python-bluetooth-mesh?

Tags: python, bluetooth, mesh, bluez

Git Repo : https://github.com/SilvairGit/python-bluetooth-mesh

**python-bluetooth-mesh/bluetooth_mesh/apps/meshcli.py** application exist
but I have no idea how to build and run the application.
Suppose if I'm run command **meshcli -h** then get the below instructions :

```
       Mesh CLI
        Usage:
            meshcli [options] [<command>...]
            meshcli -h | --help | --version

        Options:
            -l --login <login>             User login to platform service (email)
            -p --password <password>       User password to platform service (!unsecured!)
            -n --project <project>         Project name or id to be loaded from platform

            --partner <partner>            Partner identifier [default: silvair]
            --env <environment>            Environment: dev,preprod or prod [default: preprod]

            --auth0-client-id <client_id>  Auth0 client id
            --auth0-secret <secret>        Auth0 secret (!unsecured!)
            --auth0-domain <domain>        Auth0 domain name
            --serial-number <serial_num>   Gateway serial number

            -d --debug
            -h --help                      Show this help message and exit
            --version                      Show version and exit
```

But I didn't find any following **MeshCommandLine commands** on the console :

```
COMMANDS = [
        HelpCommand,
        LsCommand,
        AttentionCommand,
        SceneCommand,
        UptimeCommand,
        FaultCommand,
        VersionCommand,
        IvIndexCommand,
        ArapCommand,
        StatsCommand,
        AppVersionCommand,
        LightCommand,
        GenericOnCommand,
        GenericOffCommand,
        CompositionDataCommand,
        MorseCommand,
        NetworkTransmissionCommand,
        TtlCommand,
        RelayCommand,
        GatewayConfigurationCommand,
        GatewayPacketsCommand,
        AclCommand,
        PublicationCommand,
        SubscribeCommand,
        AddSubscriptionCommand,
        BindAppKeyCommand,
        UnsubscribeCommand,
        LightExtendedControllerCommand,
        LightRangeCommand,
        SensorCommand,
        TimeGetCommand,
        TimeCurrentSetCommand,
        TimeRoleGetCommand,
        TimeRoleSetCommand,
    ]
```

**kindly provide me with the steps of the demo application. So, I can run basic applications to understand the dbus_next.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run any of the commands by running:

```
meshcli command
```

Example:

```
meshcli HelpCommand
```

Comment: if provide above command then give it error : 
"Cannot obtain network database without Silvair commissioning API"
NotImplementedError: Cannot obtain network database without Silvair commissioning API

Comment: Apparently meshcli only works with the Silvair API. They provide a documentation, try to go through it: https://python-bluetooth-mesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest